# Underscore.js unique selection based on property name array

Tags: javascript, object, underscore.js, arrays

The following javascript is intended to take an array of objects, search for a property on each one, specified by an array of property names, and use underscore.js to to select items from the array that are unique in that aspect. For some reason, however, it returns an array with only a single object: [{type: {sub: 'a'}}]

Does anyone know why? (Using Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m, if you care.)

Thanks.

```
var objectID = ["type", "sub"];

var getFromObjectID = function(obj) {
    var result = obj;
    for(var i = 0; i < objectID.length; i++) {
        if(!result.hasOwnProperty[objectID[i]])
            return null;
        result = result[objectID[i]];
    }
    return result;
}

var array = [
    {type: {sub: "a"}},
    {type: {sub: "a"}},
    {type: {sub: "b"}},
    {type: {sub: "c"}},
    {type: {sub: "b"}},
    {type: {sub: "a"}},
    {type: {sub: "b"}},
    {type: {sub: "c"}},
    {type: {sub: "a"}},
    {type: {sub: "b"}},
    {type: {sub: "b"}},
];

var uniqueArray = _.chain(array)
        .uniq(array, function(item, key) {
            return getFromObjectID(item);
        })
        .value();
console.log(uniqueArray);
```

Comment: As long as this code is not supposed to be reusable, I would simplify it a bit :)
`_.uniq(_.pluck(_.pluck(array, 'type'), 'sub'))`

Comment: It's part of a project being crafted for fairly general use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a typo! you're using brackets instead of parentheses when doing `hasOwnProperty` check.

```
if(!result.hasOwnProperty(objectID[i]))
```

also, you haven't to add the array when calling `_uniq` since you're already chaining it:

```
 _.chain(array)
        .uniq(function(item, key) {
            return getFromObjectID(item);
        })
```

Comment: Wow. Thanks. I need to take a break from coding and take a power nap... :)